# Angularjs need to vary a parameter for each tick of angular-poller

Tags: angularjs, factory, poller

I'm following the angular-poller demo here:
https://emmaguo.github.io/angular-poller/

I need to be able to pass an argument into the factory to construct a dynamic url so that 'greet' is called with a newTime arg.

How can I modify poller.get() to pass in 'newTime'?

```
poller1 = poller.get(greet, {action: 'jsonp_get', delay: 1000});

.factory('greet', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('https://www.example.com?time=' + newTime,
        {
        },
        {
            jsonp_get: { method: 'JSONP' }
        });
})
```

/*-- Demo --*/

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource', 'emguo.poller'])

  .factory('greet1', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('https://angularjs.org/greet.php',
      {
    callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK',
    name: 'Emma'
      },
      {
    jsonp_get: { method: 'JSONP' }
      });
  })

  .factory('greet2', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('https://angularjs.org/greet.php',
      {
    callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK',
    name: 'You'
      },
      {
    jsonp_get: { method: 'JSONP' }
      });
  })

  .controller('myController', function ($scope, poller, greet1, greet2) {
    var poller1, poller2;

    /*-- Automatically start poller1 on page load --*/
    poller1 = poller.get(greet1, {action: 'jsonp_get', delay: 1000});
    poller1.promise.then(null, null, function (data) {
      $scope.data1 = data;
    });

    /*-- Actions --*/
    $scope.stop = function () {
      poller1.stop();
    };

    $scope.restart = function () {
      poller1 = poller.get(greet1);
    };

    $scope.faster = function () {
      poller1 = poller.get(greet1, {delay: 300});
    };

    $scope.slower = function () {
      poller1 = poller.get(greet1, {delay: 1500});
    };

    $scope.startPoller2 = function () {
      poller2 = poller.get(greet2, {action: 'jsonp_get', delay: 1000});
      poller2.promise.then(null, null, function (data) {
    $scope.data2 = data;
      });
    };

    $scope.stopBoth = function () {
      poller.stopAll();
    };

    $scope.restartBoth = function () {
      poller.restartAll();
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't use *angular-poller*, but seems you should be able to get what you want with the property `argumentsArray`:

```
var poller1 = poller.get(greet, {
    action: 'jsonp_get', 
    delay: 1000,
    argumentsArray: [{
        time: newTime
    }]
});
```

The array `argumentsArray`, therefore the time, is evaluated when the poller is retrieved.

---

**Edit:** After clarification, it appears you need to vary a parameter for each tick of the polling, and not when you *get* the poller. You could solve that by adding the parameter in a request interceptor:

```
// define interceptor
app.factory('requestInterceptor', function() {
    return {
        'request': function(request) {
            // if needed, wrap the following in a condition
            request.params = request.params || {};
            request.params.time = moment();
            return request;
        }
    }
})

// register interceptor
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('requestInterceptor');
})
```

Comment: I had tried this but it seems that the factory return function() is only evaluated once so that the time does not change
 
 var poller1 = poller.get(greet, {
     action: 'jsonp_get', 
     delay: 1000,
     argumentsArray: [
  {time: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')}
     ]
 });

Comment: `time` value will vary each time you will retrieve the poller, i.e. for each `poller.get` call.

Comment: You want to alter the url on every *tick* of the polling?

Comment: Yes on each tick of the polling.

Comment: You could use an interceptor for that use case. See edit.